# Trigger that doesn't allow you to introduce data if it already exists in a table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm a newbie when it comes to SQL Server and I have a problem creating a trigger.

I have a table called `Concert` and I have to create a trigger (I think?) that doesn't allow adding concerts to the database if there are already shows planned on the date that I am choosing, in the concert hall that I am choosing.

Something like

- if hall and date combination already exists in table => trigger ('not allowed')

This is my (very bad attempt):

```
CREATE TRIGGER unavailable_show
ON Concert
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT Date, HallID FROM INSERTED)  
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: Unless you need to check for overlapping time periods but really only for single points in time, don't use a trigger. Use a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: You must walk before you can run. Before you attempt a trigger, you can set up some test data containing entries that should not be allowed and write a simple select statement to retrieve them. That same logic will be needed to write a trigger. Ultimately, you need to have a good foundation of tsql skills before you attempt to write triggers.

Comment: A trigger is the wrong solution. If you have a requirement for uniqueness, use a constraint. Try this: `CREAT TABLE MYTABLE (<columns> CONSTRAINT DateHallId UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( Date, HallId ))`